# Unable to set 2 of 4 monitors to the proper resolution using AMD Radeon HD6570

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr

I am trying to replace Windows as my primary desktop OS. This is my most hardware complex installation for Ubuntu to date. I am running a fully patched fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

```
Linux MarkDesktop 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a AMD Radeon HD 6570 video card with 4 monitors attached. The 2 HP 24uh monitors work as expected. The Dell 2007FP is found by get-edid but the Viewsonic does not provide edid data. I have only tried to the the Dell to it's native 1600X1200 resolution so far. It is currently limited to 1024X768.

**get-edid -b 0  | parse-edid**

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DELL 2007FP"
ModelName "DELL 2007FP"
VendorName "DEL"
# Monitor Manufactured week 37 of 2007
# EDID version 1.3
# Digital Display
DisplaySize 410 310
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "true"
Horizsync 30-83
VertRefresh 56-76
# Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
Modeline    "Mode 0" 162.00 1600 1664 1856 2160 1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection
```

I have tried the "Mode 0" as well as the output from "gtf 1600 1200 60"

```
1600x1200 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 74.52 kHz; pclk: 160.96 MHz
Modeline "1600x1200_60.00"  160.96  1600 1704 1880 2160  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
```

and "cvt 1600 1200 60"

```
1600x1200 59.87 Hz (CVT 1.92M3) hsync: 74.54 kHz; pclk: 161.00 MHz
Modeline "1600x1200_60.00"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
```

All three were added as newmodes:

```
xrandr --newmode "Mode1" 160.96 1600 1704 1880 2160 1200 1201 1204 1242 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --newmode "Mode2" 161.00 1600 1712 1880 2160 1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "Mode0" 162.00 1600 1664 1856 2160 1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync
```

All 3 show as registered via xrandr:

```
XWAYLAND0 connected 1024x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
   Mode0         60.00  
   Mode1         60.00  
   Mode2         59.87
```

All 3 refuse to be set:

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "Mode0"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x138
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43

xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "Mode1"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x138
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43

xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "Mode2"
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x138
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Ubuntu on Xorg fixed things.